# Continuity of a function on a box $Q$ implies integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a box, and say $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is integrable on $Q$.

MY ATTEMPT:

Since $f$ is continuous on $Q$, then $f$ must be uniformly continuous on $Q$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then, we can find $\delta > 0$ such that if $x,y \in Q$ with $||x-y|| < \delta $, then we have $||f(x) - f(y)|| < \frac{ \epsilon }{Vol(Q)} $. Take a partition $P$ of $Q$ with subrectangles $\{Q_i\}_{i=1}^l$ such that

$$ \max \{ Vol(Q_i) : 1 \leq i \leq l \} < \delta$$

Since $Q_i$ is compact, we can apply the extreme value theorem to obtain points $x_i,y_i \in Q_i$ such that $f(x_i) = \sup_{x \in Q_i} \{ f(x) \} $ and $f(y_i) = \inf_{x \in Q_i} \{ f(x) \} $. By assumption, we must have $||x_i - y_i|| < \delta $. Hence

$$U(f,P) - L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^l f(x_i) Vol(Q_i) - \sum_{i=1}^l f(y_i) Vol(Q_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^l (f(x_i) - f(y_i)) Vol(Q_i) < \frac{\epsilon}{Vol(Q)} \sum_{i=1}^l Vol(Q_i) = \frac{\epsilon Vol(Q)}{Vol(Q)} = \epsilon$$

Hence, $f$ must be integrable.

Is this a correct solution? any feedback/suggestion would be extremely appreciated. thanks